# Create a unique ID based on 2 columns of data in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, unique

Create a unique id based on 2 sets of criteria in sheets

[image]

Comment: I have 2 columns i need to associate and id based on matching criteria of 2 columns as shown in the picture.  Please click on the header (underlined)

Comment: What excel version do you have?

Comment: office 365.  I also use google sheets which i prefer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Button please when posting any query, do specify and explain with details it helps members to provide solutions accordingly, I provided a solution based on assumption.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is what I have tried, this is based on the date and the location, works with Excel, as OP mentioned is using MS365, hence may follow this

[image]

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C1,MATCH(1,(A2=A$1:A2)*(B2=B$1:B2),0)),MAX(C$1:C1)+1)
```

Works in Google Sheet as well,

[image]

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C1,MATCH(1,(A2=A$1:A2)*(B2=B$1:B2),0)),MAX(C$1:C1)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="";;COUNTIF(A2:A&B2:B; A2:A&B2:B)))
```